# How to convert horizontal bar graph to vertical graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the accuracy of all models in bar graph but I am getting horizontal graph instead of vertical graph as you show the axis has been changed. How to correct it? Moreover, I want to print the accuracy score on top of each bar in the given box. Please help me out.

```
#plotting bar graph of all model's accuracy.

x=['LR','KNN','SVM','DT']
height=[LR_score,KNN_score,SVC_score,DT_score]
acc=  [round(x,2) for x in height] 

plt.barh(x,acc)

plt.xlabel("Algorithms")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy Score")

for index, value in enumerate(acc):
    plt.text(value, index, str(value))
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wse0I.png)

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html change plt.barh(x,acc) to plt.bar(x,acc)

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help. It changed vertically but the accuracy score value is ranging very very far from the plot without proper alignment.

Comment: Check if my comment solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=['LR','KNN','SVM','DT']
height=[LR_score,KNN_score,SVC_score,DT_score]
acc =  [round(x,2) for x in height] 

plt.bar(x,acc)

plt.xlabel("Algorithms")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy Score")

for value, index in enumerate(acc):
    plt.text(value, index, str(acc[value]))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Now I am getting 0,1,2,3 on each bar with proper alignment. I just want to print the accuracy score.

Comment: Oh I see.  I changed the code, now?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help, Pro Programmer!

Comment: Don't forget to check the answer is the correct one :) and glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You'e using `plt.barh` which is a function to exclusively produce horizontal bars, that's why the `h` at the end of `bar` (doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar))

For vertical bars the default function is `plt.bar` (doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar))

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks for the help!